# Use a div by class as background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

So I have a css styled div with `class="orientation"` which shows a very specific loading circle which i can not reproduce with an image.

I want to use this same div with `class="orientation"` as a background image.

Until now I was using:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 1000px; background-image: url('../images/divbg.png')">
```

But now I want to use something like this:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 1000px; background-image: div('orientation')">
```

Is this possible without any script and how?

Comment: Pure CSS won't accept that value. Only URL or gradient: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: @m4n0 ok i understand.